# Copy a section of a string into buffer in C

Tags: c, printf

I have a `char buffer[ 32 ];`
and there is a `sourceString`, which I'm not sure how it is defined, but I don't think it matters.

`sourceString` is `"abcdefgh"`

To copy `"cdef"` it into the buffer I make use of `snprintf`:

`snprintf( buffer, 4 + 1, "%s", sourceString + 2 );`

where 4 is the size of the copied section and 2 is the index of the first character in the section

It works, but I am worried about a few things causing a problem:

1. Buffer size is bigger than the string. Does it hurt to have some slack there?
2. `sourceString + 2` doesn't modify the `sourceString` or does it? I don't understand how exactly this works.
3. Are there any risks of memory leaks in this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are wasting a bit of memory here in byes (32 - (4 + 1)) = 27.  It's ok to do, and a fairly common technique both for a compile-time allocation like there, or a run-time allocation.  Do, however, use a #define instead of your magic 4, 2 and 32 numbers:

```
#define BUFFER_LEN 32
#define SOURCE_SUBSTR_LEN 4
#define SOURCE_OFFSET 2

char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
...
```

2. No, it simply calculates an address that is 2 elements from the start of the string.  You can also express this as `&sourceSring[2]` if you wish.
3. No. Memory leaks usually implies heap allocated memory (malloc, realloc, calloc) and `buffer[32]` is allocated at compile time (on the stack).

Consider using `strncpy` (or `memcpy`) instead of `snprintf`.

Comment: I'd prefer an enum over a macro as a constant